# Need help in understanding ARM Assembly count code

Tags: assembly, arm

I code in my spare time it helps me understand programming through trial and error. I recently came across this arm assembly code, it has comments but i don't seem to understand it properly. This code counts the number of characters and displays on the terminal. can someone please explain it?

```
    .global main
main:
    LDR R0, [R1, #4]        @ get argv[1]
    LDR R1, =r              @ set mode to 'r' read
    BL fopen                @ call fopen
    LDR R1, =fin            @ get var address for fin
    STR R0, [R1]            @ store result of fopen in fin
loop:                       @ loop until EOF
    LDR R0, =fin            @ get fin
    LDR R0, [R0]            @ get what's stored at fin (FILE *)
    BL getc                 @ get next char in fin
    CMP R0, #-1             @ if the char is EOF, exit loop
    BEQ printarr
    MOV R2, #4           @ 4 is size of 1 word
    MUL R1, R0, R2          @ get the array offset
    LDR R3, =array          @ store start addr of array
    ADD R3, R1              @ get adrr of array + offset
    LDR R4, [R3]            @ get the current value stored
    ADD R4, #1           @ increment that value
    STR R4, [R3]            @ store inceremented value
    B loop
printarr:
    MOV R5, #0           @ set array counter to 0
loop2:
    LDR R4, =array          @ store begining of array at R4
    CMP R5, #256            @ check if counter is 256
    BEQ exit                @ if it is, exit
    MOV R6, #4
    MUL R6, R5              @ get array offset
    ADD R6, R4              @ address of offset
    LDR R6, [R6]            @ value at offset
    CMP R6, #0           @ check if value at offset is 0
    BEQ loop2end            @ if it is, skip the printing
    LDR R0, =f1             @ store the format string at R0 (first arg)
    MOV R1, R5              @ store the counter at R1+R2 (second & third args)
    MOV R2, R1
    MOV R3, R6              @ store value at offset in R3 (fourth args)
    PUSH {R5}               @ save the counter
    BL printf               @ call printf with args R0,R1,R2,R3
    POP {R5}                @ retrieve counter
loop2end:
    ADD R5, #1           @ increment counter
    B loop2                 @ loop around again
exit:
    LDR R0, =fin
    LDR R0, [R0]
    BL fclose
    MOV R0, #0
    MOV R7, #1
    SWI 0
.data
fin: .word 0
r: .asciz "r"
f1: .asciz "ASCII %3d - {%c}: %d\n"
array:  .rept 256
        .word 0
        .endr
```

Comment: Please clarify exactly which parts that you don't understand.

Comment: @michael can you please explain loop2 onwards. Thank you.

Comment: or if you could just explain the loop2 that would be really helpful.  Thanks.  @Michael

Comment: That's... some terrible code - I wouldn't necessarily recommend learning a language from the examples of people who don't really understand it either. It seems to be simply iterating over the array calling printf for each non-zero element, just in an incredibly overcomplicated and inefficient manner.

Comment: what do you mean by non-zero element.? Sorry im new to ARM. Thanks. @Notlikethat

Comment: Er, that's nothing to do with ARM, it's a _fundamental programming concept_ - arrays are composed of elements; those elements have values; numerically, those values may or may not be 0. In other words, "check if value at offset is 0... if it is, skip the printing" means exactly what it sounds like.

Comment: Ohhhhh. I get it now. Thanks for explaining.  @Notlikethat

Comment: I have another question. How can i make this code more efficient and less complicated ?